# Как реализовать паралакс?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

как тут https://toccata.com.ua/

```css
.image {
  background-image: url(http://toccata.com.ua/uploads/main-bg.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: scroll;
  background-position: top center;
  padding: 200px 0;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  color: #333333;
  background-color: #fff;
  line-height: 1.2;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

.image h1, .image p {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<section class="image">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>title title</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloremque in provident enim placeat tenetur repudiandae illum consequatur quaerat adipisci autem! Recusandae amet inventore aut modi, itaque eaque incidunt totam nemo.</p>
  </div>
</section>

<section class="content">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>title title</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloremque in provident enim placeat tenetur repudiandae illum consequatur quaerat adipisci autem! Recusandae amet inventore aut modi, itaque eaque incidunt totam nemo.</p>
  </div>
</section>

<section class="content">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>title title</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloremque in provident enim placeat tenetur repudiandae illum consequatur quaerat adipisci autem! Recusandae amet inventore aut modi, itaque eaque incidunt totam nemo.</p>
    
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloremque in provident enim placeat tenetur repudiandae illum consequatur quaerat adipisci autem! Recusandae amet inventore aut modi, itaque eaque incidunt totam nemo.</p>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ох, ну сколько можно одно и тоже спрашивать...

В общем, как-то так...

```js
window.addEventListener('scroll', (e) => {
  const { top } = document.body.getBoundingClientRect();
  bg.style.top = (top / 3) + 'px';
});
```

```css
#bg { background-size: cover;
      background-attachment: scroll;
      background-position: top center;
      background-image: url(http://toccata.com.ua/uploads/main-bg.jpg);
      height: 100vh; width: 100vw; top: 0; 
      position: fixed; z-index: -2; 
      /* элемент на заднем плане под body */}
section { background: #fff; }
.container { padding: 0 1rem 0 1rem; }
.image { background: transparent; }
/* в .image больше нет картинки, но сам блок нужен как 
   распорка, занимающая место. */
.image .container { padding: 30vh 1rem 0 1rem;
  text-shadow: 0 0 3px #000, /* тут просто усилил тень */
               0 0 3px #000, 
               0 0 3px #000, 
               0 0 3px #000; }
/* html { scroll-snap-type: y mandatory; } */
body { margin: 0; padding: 0;
       width: 100%; min-height: 100vh;
       overflow-x: hidden; color: #333333;
       background-color: transparent;
       line-height: 1.2; font-weight: normal;
       font-style: normal;
       /* <body> должен быть прозрачным */ }
h1 { padding: 0; margin: 0;
     background: #fff; color: #000;
     position: sticky; top: 0; 
     /* Заголовки сделал прилипающими */ }
.image p { color: #fff; }
section { height: 100vh;
    /* Высоту секции поставил по высоте окна, можно поменять */
    /*  scroll-snap-align: start;
     Это принудительно останавливает скрол на нужных местах */}
```

```html
<section class="image">
  <h1>title1</h1>
  <div class="container">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloremque in provident enim placeat tenetur repudiandae illum consequatur quaerat adipisci autem! Recusandae amet inventore aut modi, itaque eaque incidunt totam nemo.</p>
  </div>
</section>
<div id="bg"></div>
<section class="content">
  <h1>title2</h1>
  <div class="container">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloremque in provident enim placeat tenetur repudiandae illum consequatur quaerat adipisci autem! Recusandae amet inventore aut modi, itaque eaque incidunt totam nemo.</p>
  </div>
</section>
<section class="content">
  <h1>title3</h1>
  <div class="container">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloremque in provident enim placeat tenetur repudiandae illum consequatur quaerat adipisci autem! Recusandae amet inventore aut modi, itaque eaque incidunt totam nemo.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloremque in provident enim placeat tenetur repudiandae illum consequatur quaerat adipisci autem! Recusandae amet inventore aut modi, itaque eaque incidunt totam nemo.</p>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: спасибо, но в примере более плавно вроде. Не подскажете, пожалуйста, что добавить еще нужно?

Comment: @ DiD, не совсем понимаю.. Мне кажется, что тут задача не такая простая

Comment: Возможно, дело в маштабе. Так то именно все просто. Но можно поиграть с коэффициентами. Установил скорость движения картинки поделив скорость скрола на 5. Плюс добавил залипающие заголовки на каждый слайд. Можно дополнительно сделать принудительную остановку скроллинга на каждом слайде.

Comment: @olyaromanenko добавил комментарии

Comment: @ DiD так оно после скрола вниз- скролит вверх. по ссылке наоборот

Comment: @olyaromanenko Последнее не понял. Это как?

Comment: @ DiD. делаю скролл - идет скролл плавный  куда проскролили..Тоесть делаю скролл вверх - плавный скролл вверх. Вниз- плавный скролл вниз. Так в примере.. У Вас же так - не так

Comment: @olyaromanenko Я закомментировал правила CSS которые отвечали за прокрутку: `scroll-snap-type` и `scroll-snap-align`